# FETCH NEXT FROM WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN taking too long

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor, sql-server-2016

The stored procedure takes 2 minutes to return results
I realized the query checks through all the records and fetches all the records.

```
OPEN cFolders
FETCH NEXT FROM cFolders INTO @FId
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
  IF @FolderPath IS NOT NULL
    SET @FolderPath = @FolderPath + '/' +
      (SELECT [FileManager_Folders].FolderName
         FROM [FileManager_Folders]  
         WHERE [FileManager_Folders].Id = @FId)
  ELSE
    SET @FolderPath =
      CASE
        WHEN @FId <> @SharedFolderId AND @ObjectTypeId = 1 THEN
          (SELECT dbo.Projects.ProjectName
             FROM dbo.Projects
             WHERE dbo.Projects.Id =
               (SELECT [FileManager_Folders].ObjectId
                  FROM [FileManager_Folders]
                  WHERE [FileManager_Folders].Id = @FId))
        WHEN @FId <> @SharedFolderId AND @ObjectTypeId = 9 THEN
          (SELECT dbo.Asset_Properties.Name
             FROM dbo.Asset_Properties
             WHERE dbo.Asset_Properties.Id =
               (SELECT [FileManager_Folders].ObjectId 
                  FROM [FileManager_Folders]
                  WHERE [FileManager_Folders].Id = @FId))
        ELSE
          (SELECT [FileManager_Folders].FolderName     
             FROM [FileManager_Folders]
             WHERE [FileManager_Folders].Id = @FId)
        END

   FETCH NEXT FROM cFolders INTO @FId
END
CLOSE cFolders
DEALLOCATE cFolders
RETURN ISNULL(@FolderPath,'')
END
```

I just want top 100 results. Not sure what to do...

Comment: Welcome to SO! What database server/version?

Comment: So you're showing us a cursor operation that takes too long - whilst not showing us the *query that the cursor executes*. You've also been very vague about what the problem is. We're not mind readers, and there's no magical "make queries quick" option that you can turn on.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  As has been mentioned, there are some things we need you to do to give us a better idea of your issue and what other solutions might be available.  Please see [ask] and [mcve] for details.

Comment: If nothing else you could add a counter to the loop, e.g. `declare @FoldersProcessed as Int = 0;`, increment the count in the loop (`set @FoldersProcessed += 1;`) and exit when it reaches the target value. Since each pass through the loop overwrites the value of `@FolderPath` it isn't clear why you go to the trouble of figuring out the first 99 of them.

Comment: Please edit your question (using the `edit` link at the bottom of the question) rather than posting your replies to comments as _answers_. You can reply to comments by using the `add a comment` link after the comments. If you want to direct the comment to a specific user then start the comment with an at sign ("@") and then user's name, e.g. "@HABO - Why a duck?"

Answer (score 0):

So you're showing us a cursor operation that takes too long - whilst not showing us the query that the cursor executes. You've also been very vague about what the problem is. We're not mind readers, and there's no magical "make queries quick" option that you can turn on. – Damien_The_Unbeliever

```
    DECLARE @ObjectTypeId BIGINT 
    SET @ObjectTypeId = (SELECT ObjectTypeId FROM [FileManager_Folders] WHERE Id = 
    @FolderId)

    DECLARE @FolderPath NVARCHAR(3000)
    DECLARE @SharedFolderId BIGINT
    SET @SharedFolderId = (SELECT Id FROM [FileManager_Folders] WHERE ObjectId = -1 AND 
    ParentId IS NULL)
    DECLARE @FId AS NVARCHAR(200)
    DECLARE cFolders CURSOR FOR
    WITH Folders (FolderId, ParentId, FolderName) AS
    (
     SELECT
     F.Id, F.ParentId, F.FolderName
    FROM dbo.[FileManager_Folders] F
    WHERE F.Id = @FolderId
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
     F.Id, F.ParentId, F.FolderName
    FROM dbo.[FileManager_Folders] F
     INNER JOIN Folders P ON P.ParentId = F.Id
     )SELECT FolderId FROM Folders ORDER BY ParentId ASC

    OPEN cFolders
   FETCH NEXT FROM cFolders INTO @FId
    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
    IF @FolderPath IS NOT NULL   SET  @FolderPath = @FolderPath + '/' + (SELECT 
    [FileManager_Folders].FolderName FROM [FileManager_Folders]  WHERE 
    [FileManager_Folders].Id = @FId)
    ELSE  SET @FolderPath = CASE WHEN @FId <> @SharedFolderId AND @ObjectTypeId = 1  THEN  
     (SELECT dbo.Projects.ProjectName FROM dbo.Projects WHERE dbo.Projects.Id = 
                            (SELECT [FileManager_Folders].ObjectId FROM 
    [FileManager_Folders]  WHERE [FileManager_Folders].Id = @FId))
                        WHEN @FId <> @SharedFolderId AND @ObjectTypeId = 9  THEN  (SELECT 
    dbo.Asset_Properties.Name FROM dbo.Asset_Properties WHERE dbo.Asset_Properties.Id = 
                            (SELECT [FileManager_Folders].ObjectId FROM 
   [FileManager_Folders]  WHERE [FileManager_Folders].Id = @FId))
                            ELSE (SELECT [FileManager_Folders].FolderName FROM 
    [FileManager_Folders]  WHERE [FileManager_Folders].Id = @FId)
                            END

    FETCH NEXT FROM cFolders INTO @FId
    END
CLOSE cFolders
DEALLOCATE cFolders

RETURN ISNULL(@FolderPath,'')

END
```